# while connecting java with mysq using Apache Tommy DataSource its giving error java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException:

Tags: java, mysqli

i am connecting java with mysql using DataSource and i am using apache tommy when i am perform any operation its throwing exception
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: ONE

i created the context.xml.

```
        <Context>
          <Resource name="jdbc/mydb" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
           maxActive="50" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
           username="root" password="root" 
           driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
           url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb"/>             

       </Context>
```

and i created the entry in web.xml

```
   <resource-ref>
     <description>MySQL Datasource example</description>
     <res-ref-name>jdbc/mydb</res-ref-name>
     <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
     <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
   </resource-ref>
```

and my servlet file is

```
             try
    {

        Context initContext = new InitialContext();
        Context envContext  = Context)initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
        DataSource ds = (DataSource)envContext.lookup("jdbc/mydb");
        Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
        Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select *From one");
        System.out.println(rs.toString());


    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

i do not know where is wrong in my code.

Comment: show the stacktrace error

Answer (score 0):

You need an space in:

```
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * From one");
```

Comment: not this problem i try then too same error and i am using eclipse

Comment: show the stack trace error you get (anyway the select was not ok)